# Inclusion-Exclusion: INTELLIGENT permutations

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many ways are there to arrange the letters in INTELLIGENT with at least two consecutive pairs of identical letters?

I got an answer of

$$C(5,2)\cdot\frac{9!}{2!^3}-C(5,3)\cdot\frac{8!}{2!^2}+C(5,4)\cdot\frac{7!}{2!}-6!\;,$$

but the solution manual says

$$C(5,2)\cdot\frac{9!}{2!^3}-2\cdot C(5,3)\cdot\frac{8!}{2!^2}+3\cdot C(5,4)\cdot\frac{7!}{2!}-4\cdot 6!\;.$$

Where am I going wrong?
can someone explain where the $2\cdot,3\cdot$, and $4\cdot$ are coming from in the solution manual?

Answer (score 1):

Given subsets $A_1,\cdots, A_n$ of a finite set S,

let $T_k=\sum|A_{i_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}|$ for $1\le k\le n$, where the sum is taken over all k-subsets of $\{1,\cdots n\}$.

If we let $N_m$ be the number of elements in at least m of the sets, then

$\displaystyle N_m=T_m-\binom{m}{m-1}T_{m+1}+\binom{m+1}{m-1}T_{m+2}-\binom{m+2}{m-1}T_{m+3}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-m}\binom{n-1}{m-1}T_n$,

as can be seen by determining how many times an element in r of the subsets is counted.

In this particular problem, $n=5$ and $m=2$.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still seeking a combinatorial interpretation as to where the "2, 3, and 4" factors come from as originally inquired:

We include the count with two consecutive pairs of identical letters. There is only 1 way to pair off two consecutive positions (from - -, only - -)
$$1{5 \choose 2} \frac {9!}{2!2!2!}$$

We exclude the count with three consecutive pairs of identical letters. There are only 2 ways to pair off 3 consecutive positions. Observe: from - - -, we can pair them off as (- -) - OR - (- -)
$$2{5 \choose 3} \frac {8!}{2!2!}$$

We include the count with four consecutive pairs of identical letters. There are only 3 ways to pair off 4 consecutive positions. Observe: from - - - -, we can pair them off as (- -) - -,     - (- -) -, OR - - (- -)
$$3{5 \choose 4} \frac {7!}{2!}$$

I hope this line of reasoning is clear for the last term $4\frac{6!}{1!}$ $5 \choose 5$